# Perl: Want to add and then average columns of tab delimited data

Tags: arrays, perl, sorting

Data is a table that includes names in the first row and first column so I keep getting a non-numeric value error. I figured out how to ignore the first row by using if ($row[0] ne "retrovirus" ), but I don't know how to ignore the first column. I am new to programming and having a really hard time understanding arrays and how to get them to work. How do I split my data into columns of numbers excluding the words and add them together?
This is what I have so far, and its giving incorrect answers.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w
use strict;

# Part A. Computing the average bp length of the virus's
# genomes and each individual gene in the text file.

my $infile = "lab1_table.txt";
open INFILE, $infile or die "$infile: $!";
my @totals = ();
while (my $line = <INFILE>){
    chomp $line;
    my $total = 0;
    my $n = 0;
    # Splitting into columns
    my @row = split /\t/, $line;

    # Working through and adding up each column
    foreach my $element (@row) {
        # Ignoring first line with headings
        if ($row[0] ne "retrovirus" ){
            $total = $total + $element;
            print "$total \n";
        }
    }
}

close INFILE;
```

Comment: Its better to show your data and expected output.

Comment: Please show your data

Comment: You can ignore the first line with the headings by simply saying `<INFILE>;` or more verbose `undef = <INFILE>;` after your `open INFILE` statement. Also note that it's better style to use a lexical filehandle and three-argument-open: `open my $fh, '<', $infile or die "$infile: $!";`. Well done on the `die` part though! See http://perldoc.perl.org/perlopentut.html for more information on that, and also http://perldoc.perl.org/perlfaq5.html#How-can-I-open-a-file-with-a-leading-%22%3e%22-or-trailing-blanks%3f.

Answer (score 0):

If you totally don't care about the first element of the row, just use `shift(@row)`
before the foreach loop. Or if you want to preserve the original values you can get the elements from the second to the last:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w
use strict;

# Part A. Computing the average bp length of the virus's
# genomes and each individual gene in the text file.

my $infile = "lab1_table.txt";

open INFILE, $infile or die "$infile: $!";
while (my $line = <INFILE>)
{
    chomp $line;
    my $total = 0;
    # Splitting into columns
    my @row = split /\t/, $line;

    # Working through and adding up each column
    if ($row[0] ne "retrovirus" )
    {
        map { $total += $_ } @row[1..(scalar(@row) - 1)];
        print "$total \n";
    }
}

close INFILE;
```